# JS файлы в каталоге с TS файлами. Это нормально?

Tags: angular2, visual-studio-2017

Заметил, что рядом с некоторыми моими ts-скриптами появились js скрипты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, это нормально или такого быть не должно?

На сколько я знаю, они должны в отдельную папку ложиться после компиляции.

Comment: Отключи автоматическую компиляцию в настройках.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а это не лишит меня возможности, что ангуляр при запущенном сервере автоматом все перекомпилирует?

Comment: Ну так компилирует же webpack, а не VS?